Show a ring is commutative if $r^2 = r + r$
The claim is that any ring $R$ in which for all $r \in R$ we have that $rr = r + r$, must be commutative. No assumptions are made about $R$ having multiplicative identity or being commutative. I was told from a professor that it was true. So far, I've found that a ring with this property cannot have a $1$ element distinct from $0$ since $1^2 = 1 + 1 = 1$, meaning $1 = 0$. I also have that every element is nilpotent with a degree at most $3$. This comes from
\begin{equation*}
(r+r)(r+r) = (r+r) +(r+r) \\
r^2 + r ^2 + r^2 + r^2 = r^2+r^2 \\
r^2 + r^2 = 0 \\
r^4 = 0.
\end{equation*}
Expanding $r^3$ then gives
\begin{equation*}
r^3 = r(r^2) \\
r^3 = r(r + r) \\
r^3 = r^2 + r^2 \\
r^3 = 0.
\end{equation*}
The other more notable result that I've managed to prove is that $ab = -ba$ for all $a, b \in R$. This can be found from expanding
\begin{equation*}
a^2 + b^2 = (a + a) + (b + b) \\
a^2 + b^2 = (a + b) + (a + b) \\
a^2 + b^2 = (a + b)(a + b) \\
a^2 + b^2 = a^2 + ab + ba + b^2 \\
ab = -ba
\end{equation*}
It feels like I'm really close but I'm not really sure where to go from here. From the above, it seems like for R to commute you would need that $ab + ab = (ab)^2 = 0$. I've continued to look at other expansions from the $r^2 = r + r$ identity and have been able to develop some other equations, but have had no success in proving commutativity yet.

You also get $4ab=0$: $2ab=ab+ab=abab=(-ba)(-ba)=(ba)(ba) = ba+ba = 2ba= -2ab$.

That means $(a+b)^2 - (a-b)^2 = 4ab=0$, so $(a+b)^2 = (a-b)^2$. This gives $4b=0$.

Yes, although this follows from $r^4 = 0$ since $4r = r^4 = 0$. If it helps at all I also have that $abab = a(-ab)b = -a^2b^2$.

@ArturoMagidin:  so such a ring has characteristic two or four?  An example of such a ring would be the subring of $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ consisting of the equivalence classes of $0$ and $2$?

Another example would be the subring of $\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z$ consisting of the equivalence classes of $0, 2, 4, $ and $6$

From $(ab)^4 = 0$ and $ab=-ba$, we have
$$\begin{align*}
ab - ba &= ab + ab \\
&= (ab)^2 \\
&= -a^2b^2 \\
&= -(a+a)(b+b) \\
&= -4ab \\
&= -((ab+ab)+(ab+ab)) \\
&= -((ab)^2 + (ab)^2) \\
&= -(ab)^4 \\
&= 0
\end{align*}$$
so that $ab = ba$.

Did $4ab=0$ come from the comment?

@J.W.Tanner I've rewritten the answer so it doesn't reference results primarily found in the comments.
